# How to deal with image references in CSS in a Rails 3.1 app

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I just upgraded my rails app to 3.1 and I'm making use of the new asset pipeline. With the pipeline in place it's imperative that any static references made in your application utilize the rails helper methods, ie, asset_path(...), img_tag(), etc....

Here's the question, how do I fix the static references in my css files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rails' SASS files, there's an `image-url()` function you can use like so:

```
.page {
    background: #eee image-url('somefile.png');
}
```

Rails will look for that file in all the asset images directories, such as `app/assets/images/somefile.png`.

Check the [readme for sass-rails](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails) for more helper methods, as well as the [Asset Pipeline Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) for further documentation and explanation.

Comment: Thanks Chris, seems like your answer is probably the right one. Please excuse my lack of knowledge here as this is the first time I'm using Rails 3.1 and SCSS. I changed the file ext of the css file to .css.scss then ran rake assets:precompile but got an error message notifying me that one of my pictures isn't precompiled. Any more hints? Thanks again.

Comment: I'm fairly new to it as well, so I can only guess as to what's causing that error. My guess would be if any of your `image-url()` images (referenced in your scss files) aren't in an `assets/images` directory (or subdirectory), you'd get that error. Just a guess, though.

Comment: thanks for the response, I do have the picture in the assets/images folder, should have mentioned that earlier.

Comment: You win, I needed a browser cache flush

Answer (score 0):

If you work with in engine or plugin, this might not work. In any case you can always use the generic method:

```
asset-url("rails.png", image)
```