# Upgrading to Ruby on Rails 3.1: How to solve image loading issues in CSS files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, image

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.10 and I am upgrading my RoR to the version 3.1.0. I am following the [Upgrading to Rails 3.1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/282-upgrading-to-rails-3-1) railscast and on the time *07:04* he starts to talk about problems on loading image files...

In few words:

> [...] This (that is, image loading - more information [here](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/282-upgrading-to-rails-3-1)) won’t work as our application’s images are no longer in the /public/images directory. The simplest solution might appear to be to change the image’s URL from /images/railscasts_logo.png to /assets/railscasts_logo.png and while this will appear to work in development mode we’ll run into issues in production. [...] We should instead always use the helper methods. This will link the image correctly in both development and production mode. [...]

*My problem is in my CSS files* where I have statements like the following

```
.a_class {
    ...
    background-image: url("/images/avatar.png");
    ...
}
```

that, as well as it should be, do not load correctly image files.

**How can I solve that problem in Rails 3.1?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might have a look into railsguides, especially the part on the asset pipeline (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

In section *2.2.2 CSS and SASS* you'll find the following explanation:

> When using the asset pipeline, paths to assets must be re-written and sass-rails provides _url and _path helpers for the following asset classes: image, font, video, audio, javascript, stylesheet.
>
> ```
> image-url("rails.png") becomes url(/assets/rails.png)
> image-path("rails.png") becomes "/assets/rails.png".
> ```
>
> The more generic form can also be used but the asset path and class must both be  specified:
>
> ```
> asset-url("rails.png", image) becomes url(/assets/rails.png)
> asset-path("rails.png", image) becomes "/assets/rails.png"
> ```

There is also an alternavtive way by adding an .erb-extension instead of the default .sass, which is described in section 2.2.1. But I prefer the sass-way anyway.

**Edit:**

You might also want to check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375568/how-to-deal-with-image-references-in-css-in-a-rails-3-1-app) here on stackoverflow.